# iterate simultaneously over two lists using thymeleaf

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, iterator, thymeleaf

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Roles
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <thbody>
        <td><th:block th:each="myRoles : ${MyRoles}">
            <input type="checkbox" name="roles"
                th:value="${myRoles .id}" checked />
            <label th:text="${myRoles .roleName}"></label>
        </th:block>--</td>
    </thbody>
```

> Current it is showing me only one list(present roles), I want to show all roles which are bind in object ${AllRoles} and checked only those roles which are currently given to a particular user.

I am trying to save roles in set in my controller:

```
Set<UserRole> myRolesSet;
myRolesSet= myusr.getRoles();
```

Here's how I am trying to do in view:

```
<thbody >
        <td><th:block th:each="allRoles : ${allrole}">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="roles" th:value="${allRoles.id}"
        th:checked="${#sets.contains(myRolesSet,allRoles.id)}? 'checked' " />
        <label th:text="${allRoles.roleName}"></label>
        </th:block></td>
</thbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this like the following code sample:

***First you need to put selected roles in a Map in your controller method as follows:***

```
HashMap<Integer, Role> myRolesMap = new HashMap<Integer, Role>();
```

In this case I assume you are using an Integer key for your hash map.

***Secondly you have to iterate over AllRoles list and decide if the user has the currently iterated Role then you should check the checkbox.***

```
    <thbody>
        <td><th:block th:each="role: ${AllRoles}">
            <input type="checkbox" name="roles"
                th:value="${role.id}" th:checked="${#maps.containsKey(myRolesMap, role.id)}" />
            <label th:text="${role.roleName}"></label>
        </th:block>--</td>
    </thbody>
```

Comment: Hi Ahmet,i have added updated code,tried to do it like this.But it is still not working.

Comment: Are you putting users roles in a map as i stated in my answer (you should do this in your controller).

Comment: I am putting them in a SET(at my controller end). Can't that work?

Comment: Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#maps.containsKey(myRolesMap,allRoles.id)"

Comment: this exception occurs if i am using hasmap or a set

Comment: Maybe there is a little typo in the code; please check it. The code sample i gave you is the way i handle such situations.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmet I changed the method acc. to my requirement, now it's working perfectly.